# how to trigger childNode click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a parent DIV and it has many child divs. Those child divs are clickable, and I am trying to trigger click event on each divs in order  with  setInterval(funcLoop, 5000)

```
....
setInterval(funcLoop, 5000);
....
....
function funcLoop()
{
    var c = document.getElementById("divParent").childNodes;
    c[index].click();
    index++;
    if (index == document.getElementById("divParent").childNodes.length)
        index = 0;
}
```

But, I am getting the error below

```
Uncaught TypeError: c[index].click is not a function
```

can anybody tell me what I should do to fix this?

Comment: what is `c[index].click();`?

Comment: c[] stores all childNodes, and I am trying to access each one of them by index to trigger click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`childNodes` also includes text nodes and comments, which does not have `click` handlers.

Replace `childNodes` with `children`, or do

```
setInterval(funcLoop, 5000);
....
....

function funcLoop() {
    var c = document.getElementById("divParent").children;

    for (var i=c.length; i--;) {
        c[i].click();
    }
}
```